# ElasticSearch problem when I try to save a new product. Error: "Limit of total fields [1000] has been exceeded"

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a problem when I try to save a product in my collection. When I try to save the product number 271 I obtain this error

> Error creating entity in index product_ids: Invalid Elasticsearch response built from a unsuccessful (400) low level call on PUT: /product_ids/_doc/myproduct

> Exception: Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 400 from: PUT /product_ids/_doc/myproduct. ServerError: Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "Limit of total fields [1000] has been exceeded"

I thought that the problem was due to the fact that the sum of all the fields of my products was greater than 1000 but if I remove a compound field within the product I end up inserting even more than a thousand products in the index. What could be the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61421537/limit-of-total-fields-crossed-more-than-1000-elasticsearch-exception

Comment: I am not sure because if I remove a compound filed (as I wrote) my batch process could insert more than 1000 fields..at the moment I am at 10984 and it still work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch by default will give you 1000 field limit for each index for performance purposes. You can increase the field limit using this:

```
PUT product_ids(your index)/_settings
{
  "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000
}
```

2000 would be the new field limit.

PS: I understand needing to increase field limit but I'd suggest not to increase it too much because in large scale applications it will start to affect performance. Try to design documents different way like don't use UUIDs as key, or use a list instead of a dict if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The max size of fields is not per document but per index.
Get the mapping with `GET /product_ids/_mapping` and check what you have.

Do you really need that number of fields? May be you could design your documents in another way?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I need that number of fields, because it's a catalogue. I try to design documents in another way but probably it is not possible

Comment: Could you share your mapping? So we can tell if there are some optimizations? And a typical document?